# Using Linq Join within the Where clause of another Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to have Linq Query as below, but the not able to, its giving me compile time error any help please? The error is "inference failed to call the Join" - any help please? I want to use join within where clause of other query, is that possible?

```
Case _case = (from x in this.Context().CaseRepository.GetAll()
              where (from g in x.Violations
                     join a in this.Context().OneToManyRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.ParentEntity == "Notice" && a.ChildEntity == "Violation") 
                     on new { g.ViolationId, this.NOVId } equals new { a.ChildEntityId, a.ParentId }
                     where g.CaseId == x.CaseId 
                     select g).Count() > 0
              select x).FirstOrDefault();

this.TriggerMetaDataUpdate<Case>(_case);
this.TriggerMetaDataUpdate<InspectionResult>(this.InspectionResult);
```

Comment: It's very hard for us to help without any knowledge of the types involved. If you could provide more information, or preferably a [mcve], that would really help. It would also be simpler if you could extract the inner query from the rest - if you declare a variable of the same type as `x`, you should be able to show the problem in a much simpler way.

Comment: I *suspect* the problem is that the two anonymous types you're using have different shapes - one has properties of `ViolationId` and `NOVId`, and the other has properties of `ChildEntityId` and `ParentId`.

Comment: Isn't with the join within Where clause, do I have any syntactical error why does it give me syntax error?

Comment: Yes, the join is within the `where` clause. My point is that if you did the same join *outside* the `where` clause, you could show the same problem in half the code. It's not a *syntax* error - the problem isn't your syntax, it's type inference. As I say, I suspect it's because your join effectively says "join on this apple being equal to this orange" by using differently-shaped anonymous types... but while there's a lot of probably-irrelevant code, and not enough type information about what *is* relevant, we can't tell.

Comment: The two sides of `equals` must be of the same type. Anonymous types are of the same type when there members match in name and type. You have `{ ViolationId, NOVId }` on one side and `{ ChildEntityId, ParentId }` on the other side, so that will never work. Do something like `on new { Id1 = g.ViolationId, Id2 = this.NOVId } equals new { Id1 = a.ChildEntityId, Id2 = a.ParentId }` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way:

```
        var Violations = (from v in UnitOfWork.ViolationRepository.GetAll()
       join a in UnitOfWork.OneToManyRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.ParentEntity == "Notice" && a.ChildEntity == "Violation")
      on v.ViolationId equals a.ChildEntityId
     join b in UnitOfWork.OneToManyRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.ParentEntity == "Notice" && a.ChildEntity == "Case")
   on a.ParentId equals b.ParentId
  where b.ChildEntityId == caseId
  orderby v.ViolationId
  select v).ToList();
```

Comment: That looks significantly less efficient than changing what you had to just use the same anonymous type on both sides, as per NetMage's comment. The problem is that we *still* have no idea what the types are, etc... so it's really hard to give you concrete help.

Comment: You are right, absolutely but I finished it before reading your answer, still posted to get your suggestions and thanks a lot my friend.